# C# - Register a third party COM DLL during a pre-build event

Tags: c#, com, interop, regsvr32

I have a dependency on several COM components. My project is managed. I want to ensure that the most recent version of the COM DLL is registered pre-build. I have added regsvr32 calls on the DLLs in the pre-build step but it never seems to work correctly. When the project is built it complains that the type isn't registered. I have both isolated and non-isolated components.

How do people handle this situation? Is regsvr32 the only answer? Why does MSBuild fail to notice that the types have been registered?

Comment: The questions that come to mind for me is: Do these dependencies really change so often that they have to be registered as a pre-build step? How was the project developed to reference them if they're not already registered? Are you doing this to configure automated builds, or are you building from within the IDE?

Comment: What is the return value from `regsvr32`? Do you need elevation (running Vista/Win7 with UAC)?

Comment: @Joel - Pulling a clean build in a clean environment would cause that type of failure. In a large project, you really need this sort of thing to be automatic even if it redundant. I would do a similar thing so that the build is executable in one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regsvr32 is the way to register your typelib and COM server information in the registry. It's a trivial process, and I'm suprised that it doesn't work. Have you hand verified the process to make sure its not something else, like supplying the wrong path to regsvr32?

Comment: Ok....it could be failing now that I've mucked with it a little bit. If the path is invalid to the DLL the build will succeed but regsvr32 will fail, silently. How do you make the build fail when this happens? The build fails if the switches are wrong but not if the file path is wrong.

Comment: @Adam - I wouldn't fail the build if somebody mucks with the path as it causes runtime issues and not build issues. I see it as similar to having somebody mess with the output path for the build artifacts. It's not really a build failure in the truest sense of the word.

Comment: I definitely think it's a build issue. The DLL is not registered correctly, thus the C# assembly then fails to build because it doesn't know where the COM DLL is. Failing the build because of a failure to register would just identify the problem sooner.

Comment: Thanks for making me realize that I had to check whether or not it was functioning correctly at all though. It really helped me solve the problem.

Comment: @Adam - Right, I agree with that, but the path isn't a dynamic part of the system. Once it is configured it ought to stay that way.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by calling a batch script:

```
$(ProjectDir)register.bat "$(SolutionDir)"
```

Batch:

```
regsvr32 "%~1ThirdParty\comdll1.dll" /s
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO Exit
regsvr32 "%~1ThirdParty\comdll2.dll" /s
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO Exit
regsvr32 "%~1ThirdParty\comdll3.dll" /s
EXIT:
```

The issue is that Visual Studio can only check the ERRORLEVEL value once, at the end. If comdll2 failed to register but comdll3 succeeded then the ERRORLEVEL would be 0 and the build would not fail.